# Is "made" in this sense stative or dynamic?

Tags: stative-verbs, dynamic-verbs

> "Several subsequent voyages **were made**."

Is the verb "made" here stative or dynamic?

Comment: The verb _made_ in this sentence is a past participle, part of a Passive construction. If the passive is important to the answer, you should be asking about it; if it's not, let's unwind it: _`X` made several subsequent voyages._ The _made_ in that sentence is the only verb, and it's clearly active; i.e, it passes the syntactic tests for an active (you say 'dynamic') verb. It can be used in the imperative or the progressive, for instance; but not in the passive form, of course. Moral: don't ask generalized questions about specialized structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely dynamic. It's an action.

Stative verbs indicate: being or existence (be, remain); qualities that appeal to the senses (taste, smell, etc.); possession (have, own); desires and feelings (want, like); and thoughts (believe, know). In other words, concepts that you know exist but can't see or hear, etc.

Note that most, if not all, stative verbs have their active uses. 
http://bayan.50webs.com/eng/grammar/tenses_files/state_verb.htm

That said, these rules do not apply in Scotland, where you can frequently hear statements like: "I'm really wantin' a bit of haggis right now."

Answer (score 1):

In an unsearchable and potentially ephemeral comment to the original posting, Professor Lawler kindly presented the following answer:

> The verb *made* in this sentence is a past participle, part of a Passive construction. If the passive is important to the answer, you should be asking about it; if it’s not, let’s unwind it:
>
> - *X* made several subsequent voyages.
>
> The *made* in that sentence is the only verb, and it’s clearly active; i.e, it passes the syntactic tests for an active (you say ‘dynamic’) verb. It can be used in the imperative or the progressive, for instance; but not in the passive form, of course.
>
> Moral: don’t ask generalized questions about specialized structures.

I’ve marked this posting Community Wiki because it is John’s answer not my own, and so I deserve no reputation from it.